# Disable javascript based on screen size with $(function()

Tags: javascript, html

How do you use a `if(screen.width <= 1280) {` paramater with a `$(function () {` code?

I need the script below to only operate on desktop, based on screen size. For some reason, I can't get it to work with a script using `$(function () {`.

```
$(function () { 
    $("container").paroller();
    $(window).paroller({ factor: '0.5', type: 'foreground', direction: 'vertical' });
        });
```

Thanks!

Comment: check my solution

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you. put your desire width  on if statement and try

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width > 1200){
    //Putt your code here
    }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. When implementing that, it causes the script to run on any screen size.

Answer (score 0):

$(funciton(){}) is shorthand for document.ready. The DOM is already loaded when the code is executed.

Check the screen size inside the function.

```
$(function () { 
    $("container").paroller();

   if(screen.width <= 1280) {
      $(window).paroller({ factor: '0.5', type: 'foreground', direction: 'vertical' })
   else
       $(window).paroller({ factor: '1.5', type: 'background', direction: 'horizontal' }) //example
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely explained it, although it still causing it to not work on any screen size.